# opkg-cl update 2 download error

Tags: linux, opkg

Am trying to update using opkg-cl.  Getting the following errors.  Does anyone know how I go about troubleshooting this?

```
[root@wrap /root]$ /etc/opkg/opkg_update.sh
Downloading /Packages.gz.
Downloading file:///mnt/usb/packages/Packages.gz.
Downloading https://beacon-repo.shoppertrak.com/repos/stable/Packages.gz.
Inflating https://beacon-repo.shoppertrak.com/repos/stable/Packages.gz.
Updated list of available packages in /var/lib/opkg/lists/all-remote-shoppertrak.
Downloading https://beacon-repo.shoppertrak.com/repos/base/Packages.gz.
Inflating https://beacon-repo.shoppertrak.com/repos/base/Packages.gz.
Updated list of available packages in /var/lib/opkg/lists/all-remote-base.
Collected errors:
 * opkg_download: Failed to download /Packages.gz: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL.
 * copy_file: ///mnt/usb/packages/Packages.gz: No such file or directory.
 * file_copy: Failed to copy file ///mnt/usb/packages/Packages.gz to /tmp/opkg-8FAiHb/update-iCH5Eo/all-local.gz.
[root@wrap /root]$ ls /mnt/usb/
[root@wrap /root]$
[root@wrap /root]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more information on your configuration?
Such as:

- opkg version
- content of your opkg feeds config file /etc/opkg/*.conf)

At first glance it looks like you have a local feed configured at file:///mnt/usb/packages/, which is lacking a Package.gz file.